# Unable to get Facebook SDK for Unity running on Android

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I am unable to use the FB SDK 6.1 and 6.2 for Unity on Android 5.0 with Unity 4.6.1p4.

If I just grab the package as it is (tried both asset store and FB directly), it will crash at runtime because it can't find

com.facebook.android.R$Layout.class

This class is in the bin/classes directory (which Unity appears to ignore), but it is not in the classes.jar file.

If I delete the classes.jar file and build a new one from the files in the classes folder ("jar -cvf classes.jar ." in the classes directory), I appear to get past the Layout.class issue but instead get a null reference exception:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2951)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2982)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Which makes no sense to me at all. FB.Init appears to work - it's during FB.Login that it crashes (Between me calling Login and my callback being invoked).

Is this supposed to just work out of the box?

(FWIW, this app worked with an older version of the FB SDK)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by removing the otherwise empty AndroidManifest.xml from the SDK folder.

I have a complicated build process with many different targets so I generate my own final manifest and don't want Unity messing around with it, so I normally remove the ones in the SDK folder to prevent Unity from merging them.

I have a bunch of other Android SDKs for which this is not a problem, but apparently Unity uses the presence of the manifest to decide which files to include in the APK (and where?) and this causes problems for some SDKs.

Odd thing is, when I looked in the APK all the files appeared to be there (specifically the layout), but it must have been in the wrong location and/or format.

Anyways, lesson learned: Don't remove the manifest, even if you don't think you need it :)